# In Sharepoint 2013 AllUserData has been change

Tags: sql

Now is written as XML file. Like they told in this article: http://joelblogs.co.uk/2013/02/15/sharepoint-2013-content-databases-and-the-alluserdata-table/
How to use them in SQL ? This field and find out wchich field is for good table ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? And why do you need to write directly from database?

Comment: I want to prepere SQL query, to askSharepoint two List about their elements. And iport all of elements like in Sharepoint 2010 to the MSSQL Data Table. How to import List to DataTable in Sharepoint 2013 ?